# ViewHolder returns the old position in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a *Fragment* with *BottomSheet* behavior that contains a horizontal *RecyclerView*. *RecyclerView* is adjusted by *SnapHelper* to achieve a page effect. It looks something like this:

[image]

In the **onCreateView** event in the *Fragment*, I set *Adapter* and *LayoutManager*:

```
recycler_view.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), dataList));
recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

After I set *Adapter*, the **onCreateViewHolder** event is triggered in the *MyRecyclerAdapter* class object, followed by **onBindViewHolder**:

```
@Override
public MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view, parent);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    /**I do something using position**/
}
```

When I create this *Fragment* and configure *RecyclerView* for the first time-everything works well, **onBindViewHolder** returns the correct position. But when I flip to the 1st, 2nd, etc. element *RecyclerView*, and then recreate the fragment, for some unknown reason **onBindViewHolder** return the old (last) position, although a new *Adapter* and *LineraLayoutManager* were created.

To make it clear, I'll break it down into steps:

1. Creating a *Fragment*.
2. Creating an object of the *MyRecyclerAdapter* class. Set it in *RecyclerView*.
3. Creating an object of the *LinearLayoutManager* class. Set it in *RecyclerView*.
4. The **onBindViewHolder** event in *MyRecyclerAdapter*is triggered. I get **position = 0**.
5. I scroll to the element with **position = 2**.
6. I do detach this fragment, and then immediately attach this fragment.
7. Creating an object of the *MyRecyclerAdapter* class. Set it in *RecyclerView*.
8. Creating an object of the *LinearLayoutManager* class. Set it in *RecyclerView*.
9. The **onBindViewHolder** event in *MyRecyclerAdapter*is triggered. I get **position = 2**.

**Question:** Why do I get the old position and most importantly how do I fix it?

I read that Android specifically saves the old *ViewHolder* to use memory more efficiently, but I don't need it.

***UPD (Solution)*:** It seems to me that this is a temporary solution (not ideal), but it works. You need to run **smoothScrollToPosition(0)** after you have installed *Adapter* and *LayoutManager*. It is very important to use **smoothScrollToPosition(0)**, not **scrollToPosition(0)**:

```
recycler_view.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), dataList));
recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
recycler_view.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

***UPD.1 (Best Solution)*:** Just use this:

```
recyclerView.setSaveEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you detach and reattach the fragment then only its View hierarchy is being destroyed and recreated. Restoring scroll position is part of `RecyclerView`s state restoration behavior.

If you want your `RecyclerView` to always start at scroll 0 you can prevent it from saving its scroll state in the first place by disabling that behavior:

```
recyclerView.setSaveEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a simple and convenient solution!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Android saved automatically saves the old ViewHolder to use memory more efficiently.

If you don't need.

Then setting the adapter again or do notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I am setting the adapter again in step 7 and it doesn't help. I found a solution and added it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer is to use `holder.adapterPosition` instead of the passed `position` argument to `onBindViewHolder`.

More info [here](https://proandroiddev.com/difference-between-position-getadapterposition-and-getlayoutposition-in-recyclerview-80279a2711d1).